# Looking for a more effective method to find a specific type of GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

thanks for having a look at this post!

This function below is part of a larger script that gets a reference to a script from a separate GameObject. While everything works as intended, it is clear that using GameObject.Find() is not the most efficient method, especially as this function is one that gets called more than once at a given time, mostly as part of a foreach loop elsewhere.

```
[SerializeField] private int maximumX;
    [SerializeField] private int maximumY;

    public void Example(int x, int y)
    {
        if (x < 0 || x > (maximumX - 1) || y < 0 || y > (maximumY - 1))
        {
            Debug.LogError("Object (" + x + ", " + y + ") does not exist");
        }
        else
        {
            SampleScript targetExample = GameObject.Find("Object (" + x + ", " + y + ")").GetComponent<SampleScript>();

            //Returns three public variables from targetExample
            //Note that "x" and "targetExample.xCoordinate" are the same (as well as both Y's)
            //While the bool "isValid" varies between each "SampleScript" in the scene
            Debug.Log(targetExample + " X value: " + targetExample.xCoordinate);
            Debug.Log(targetExample + " Y value: " + targetExample.yCoordinate);
            Debug.Log(targetExample + " isValid: " + targetExample.isValid);
        }
    }
```

There are several prefabs in a given scene that have this SampleScript component and each have a unique isValid boolean, as well as an X and Y coordinate (represented by xCoordinate/yCoordinate). Each GameObject has their unique name denoting their X/Y cooridnates (e.g. "Object (1, 2)") and so far this has been my method for locating a particular object. Note that these numbers doesn't necessarily match the GameObject's world transform.

There is properly a simpler solution to this that I just completely missed, but any help will be great! Thanks!

Comment: Define `specific type of GameObject` ... you seem to go by name here so I guess besides having them somewhere stored in a dictionary beforehand the built-in `Find` probably already is the fastest for this ... So the question is: Who is spawning your `SampleScript` objects and assigns their names? -> why is it not also keeping track of the existing instances and their coordinates in e.g. a `SampleScript[,]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the objects exist at start time, iterate all GameObjects and put a reference in a Dictionary<string,GameObject> by name, which will be far more efficient to use during Update.

If the objects do not exist at start time, create the same Dictionary, but instead of pre-populating it, use ContainsKey to see if you have a reference, and if you don't then use GameObject.Find to add it to the dictionary at that time so you only take the time penalty once:

```
string key = "Object (" + x + ", " + y + ")";
if(!ObjectDict.ContainsKey(key))
{
    ObjectDict.Add(key,GameObject.Find(key));
}
SampleScript targetExample = ObjectDict[key].GetComponent<SampleScript>();
```

(If you destroy any objects, make sure to also remove them from the Dictionary)

Comment: Thank you so much, it was the first scenario where the objects existed at the start and it works perfectly! :D